# Notepad++ multi line copy paste in different lines

Tags: notepad++, csv

I have a csv file with:

```
David,33,Virginia
John,45,Alabama
Tina,33, Texas
```

Another file which contains:

```
<Person> 
      <Name>name1</Name> 
      <Age>xx</Age>
      <State>state1</State>
</Person>
```

Another file which contains:

```
<Person> 
      <Name>name2</Name> 
      <Age>xx</Age>
      <State>state2</State>
</Person>
```

Another file which contains:

```
<Person> 
      <Name>name2</Name> 
      <Age>xx</Age>
      <State>state2</State>
</Person>
```

How can I take each line from the csv file and paste them into the fields in the xml file.